# Can Windows Phone 8 SDK be installed on 32-bit Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-express

I wish to develop Metro apps as well as Windows Phone 8 apps without having to install completely separate IDEs. I read that if I have Pro or Ultimate versions of Visual Studio 2012 installed, then the SDK integrates into the existing IDE (oddly doesn't happen in case of Express editions). However my dreamspark subscription only allows me the 32-bit versions of Ultimate, and WP8 development apparently needs 64-bit configuration. I have a 64-bit OS, but no access to a 64-bit Visual Studio pack. What is my best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Visual Studio 2012 has no separate 64-bit builds, only 32-bit. So logically, WP8 development will work with a 32-bit VS12 as long as the computer running it can also run the 64-bit emulator that comes with the WP8 SDK.

The solution is to install VS12 Pro/ultimate and then install the Windows Phone 8 SDK separately.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, VS12 Pro & Ultimate should have native development support for WP8, no matter if the version installed is 32bit or 64bit.

Edit: I just checked and I am running VS12 Ultimate 32-bit myself, and I have project templates for WP8.

Comment: You are correct. I just found out that it works just fine. :)